# How to create an ACL list on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, acl

We are a few people working in an office on a server via SFTP.  We all work on the same files so it would be great if we had, by default, read/write access by default on some folders.

For example, the Web server acts as our "Web development" environment so I would like that when somebody creates a folder/file, everyone in the group "www-data" has 777 permissions to it.

I managed to set the primary group of every user to www-data so when we create files, the files have group owner "www-data" but since the files/folders have 755 permissions by default, we cannot modify someone else's work unless we modify the permissions, which becomes tedious.

I'Ve header that we can create an ACL which would allow people of group www-data to have write access to a particular folder, is that correct ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
setfacl -R -m g:www-data:rwx /folder
```

To change the the current permissions

Comment: Hello Patrick, when I issue this command, I get : chacl: access ACL 'g:www-data:rwx': Missing or wrong entry at entry 0

Comment: That's what I get from doing it from memory :)  I've updated the answer above